# lighttpd is not redirecting my http traffic

Tags: load-balancing, lighttpd

I am trying to balance the load between two hosts. In those hosts I have Apache serving `/ejemplo.html`. That works perfectly. But I have installed `lighttpd` on another machine (`192.168.56.104`) to act as load bolancer, with the following configuration:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "/.*/" {
  proxy.balance = "round-robin" 
  proxy.server  = ( "" => ( ( "host" => "192.168.56.102" ),
                            ( "host" => "192.168.56.103" ) ) )
}
```

It should redirect all http traffic to those hosts, but if I make a request with `curl` for instance:

```
curl http://192.168.56.104/ejemplo.html
```

It does not return the page ("Not found"). In addition, if I run

```
    curl http://192.168.56.104/
```

It returns the default page of `lighttpd`.

(`mod_proxy` is added in `server.modules`)

Any ideas about what's wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $HTTP["host"] =~ "/.*/" {

This is your issue.  It will only match URL paths which contain / followed by zero or more characters, and then another /, e.g. http://192.168.56.104/ejemplo.html/  Note the final trailing slash.

If you want lighttpd to send everything to those two servers, leave that $HTTP condition out:

```
proxy.balance = "round-robin" 
proxy.server  = ( "" => ( ( "host" => "192.168.56.102" ),
                          ( "host" => "192.168.56.103" ) ) )
```